# Skip processing for markdown blocks in commonmark.js

Tags: parsing, markdown, commonmark

how can I skip markdown processing for certain codeblocks?
I have Latex codeblocks in my markdown like that: \& \&
which gets processed to && and then breaks the latex processing.

I tried ```` ``` ```` but this is just for codeblock fencing.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This would require an extension which adds a new type of block. Some Markdown parsers have such an extension. However, I am not aware of any for commonmark.js or if commonmark.js even supports extensions.

Comment: hmm, what a pity. I solved it by wrapping the codeblock into `<p>` tags, this way it was left as literal code.